# How to take a screenshot of gksudo's window?

Tags: linux, screenshot, gksu

I've been configured a keyboard shortcuts and it is working with others.
it doesn't work only with gksudo's window and special system menus.
(my laptop is running with Linux Mint 18.2)

below command is just example for watching gksudo's window.

```
$ gksudo "gnome-terminal -e 'dmesg -w'"
```

how can I fix this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `gksu-properties` and set "Grab mode" on disable, now your shortcut should work.

---

Alternatively:

Add some delay to your key bindings and press it before running `gksudo`, for example using `scrot` you can run something like:

```
scrot -d 5 FILE_NAME
```

- `-d 5` 5 second dealay

Comment: wow, nice! it works on my laptop.